# how to give download link to var/export/export_customers.csv?

Tags: importexport, dataflow, enterprise-1.14

Normally after successful running export customers data flow profiles its saving data to `var/export` folder, but I want to download that file to desktop.

Can you give any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `link` var in the xml. On the backend dataflow page, add the var in the  *Profile Actions XML*

```xml
<!-- go to the last element -->
<action type="dataflow/convert_adapter_io" method="save">
    <var name="type">file</var>
    <var name="path">var/export</var>
    <var name="filename"><![CDATA[export_customers.csv]]></var>
    <var name="link">/var/export/export_customers.csv</var> <!-- add this -->
</action>
```

However, you need to configure your web server to allow access to `var/export` based on IP or other secure methods.